# Methods to detect a common area in a series of images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

**Suppose** we have a series of digital images D1,...,Dn. For certainty, we consider this images to be of the same size. The problem is to find the largest common area -- the largest area that all of the input images share.

I suppose that if we have an algorithm to detect such area in two input images A and B, we can generalize it to the case of n images.

**The most difficulty** in this problem is that this area in image A doesn't have to be identically, pixel to pixel, equal to the the same area in image B. For example, we take two shots of a building using phone camera. Our hand shook and the second picture turned out to be a little dislodged. And the noise that's present in every picture adds uncertainty as well.

What algorithms should I look into to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Give me money to fund 2 PhD students + lab material and I will write an answer!

Comment: @ Ander Biguri, so what you're saying is that nobody ever solved this problem, and there's no books or papers where such problem is considered? P.S. How much money, btw? :)

Comment: It might actually have a solution, but its definitely too broad. There is no an "answer" to this, or a single method that can be used to solve the problem. It occurs tome at least 5 or 6 different things I would try.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, well, that's exactly what I am asking for --- 5 or 6 different things to try) I understand that current formulation is rather vague. I just need something to start with. Brief google search on the matter didn't bring results.

Comment: Try to break the steps. You need image matching, and tons of other stuff.

Comment: A more formal description is needed! What kind of "errors" are possible. Limited to "translations", one might use [SAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) as matching-core (like video-codecs) and combine this with mathematical-programming or heuristics. But what about scaling/rotation/affine transformations? | How is the border-penalty (e.g. part of area in image x is non-existent; out of border)? How to calculate these errors in general if chosen area's are not of the same size (only relevant if there are geometric transformations other than translation)?

Comment: @AnderBiguri - .... yeah, looks like my DIP gold badge is going to have to wait if questions like this keep coming up.

Comment: @rayryeng you wont make us happy any time soon... last 20 DIP have been like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple but approximate solution, to begin with.

- Rescale the images so that the amplitude of the shaking becomes smaller than a pixel.
- Compute the standard deviation of every pixel across all images.
- Consider the pixels with a deviation below a threshold.

---

As a second approximation, you can use the image at the full resolution as a template, but only in the areas obtained as above. Then register the other images with respect to it. The registration model can be translational only, but allowing rotation would be better.

Unfortunately, [registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) isn't an easy task. For your small displacements, Lucas-Kanade or Shi-Tomasi might be appropriate.

After registration, you can redo the deviation test to get better delineated regions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a method like SURF (or SIFT): you compute the SURF on each image and you see if there is common interest points. The common interest points will be the zone you are looking for. Thanks to SURF, the area does not have to be at the same place or scale.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!